# Videos In Safari Render Page Incorrectly

Tags: flash, safari, render

I have a really strange issue. If I insert a flash video from YouTube, BlipTV, JW Player etc. the text on the page is jagged and the links from the "Pages" drop down menu that overlays the video are all bunched up. This problem only occurs in Safari, you can see it for yourself here: http://ghostpool.com/wordpress/reviewit/pages

I cannot pinpoint why this is happening. Anyone have any ideas?

**EDIT:** Fixed this myself by adding position: static to the list items. It seems position: relative was causing the problem.

Comment: all looks fine for me , Mac OSX Snow Leopard 10.6.4 Safari 5.0.3

Comment: @PatrickS I'm using the same version of Mac, but 5.0.1 of Safari. I'll look into upgrading, but visitors will still have this issue. When you hover over the "Pages" menu are the links not bunched up?

Comment: ok, it just happened but i had to play with it for awhile.whatever i tried was very random , so i wouldn't be able to reproduce the steps. one of the last step was the style switcher, changing style got the pages links back to normal. cool design by the way!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Fixed this myself by adding `position: static` to the list items. It seems `position: relative` was causing the problem.